# Best way to edit/delete multiple rows if they exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "roles", table "pages" and table "pages_roles".

I have multiple select field for each page "roles" and there i select all the roles for the given page.
Roles:

regular user

paid user

and so on.

The problem is this:

When I save for the first time with both roles 2 rows are inserted.

roles table:

**id=1, role=regular user
id=2, role=paid user**

roles_access:

**id=1, role_id=1, page_id=1
id=2, role_id=2, page_id=1**

On the second edit I have the following variants:

1) First delete all current roles for the given page then insert selected ones - this will increase the ids very fast on each save whether i changes something or not

The same as above but with different ids:
**id=3, role_id=1, page_id=1
id=3, role_id=2, page_id=1**

2) I delete all unselected records, then UINSERT the selected ones.
This will work - for the roles that exists nothing will happen they will preserve the id of the table(roles_pages).

But it gets little complicated.

So do you have some better or  clever approach for this.

Thank you

Comment: Please show us sample data.  Also, "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  Please tell us which database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.).

Comment: Edited, MySQL,  if something is unclear i can fix it, basically the records becomes the same only with different ids - because I delete them for the given page before insertion.

Comment: In 1): If you want to increase id range. you can give unsigned property to id column.

Comment: Maybe try to change your logic and on edit don't delete all existing roles. Basically on the front end you can save the old state and the new state of the roles, then you can decide which roles need to be deleted, updated and inserted. It is a bit more complicated logic than delete -> insert, but will be more efficient for the database :)

Comment: Maybe yes :). But this creates complexity if i want to copy the records to second database. If i delete some of the records after i send them to 2nd database, i cannot know which are has been deleted

Comment: Well you can always reuse the same logic to update both databases, depends how you manage your code. Same logic 100 databases if u wish. When updating different from the main database you can always retrieve previous state of the roles

Comment: That is true, but i want to ignore forms when synchronizing data to 2nd database. For example I want to save all roles for all pages - I dont want to prepare all forms and data  for all pages - I want only the data -for faster sync. In this case i have to change the logic to delete all records from 2nd database that are not existend in 1st database or something similar.

Comment: Maybe you should use a more enterprise grade database that does this replication for you